# Testbench issue for glowing/fading LED not producing a waveform

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog, vivado, test-bench

I was working through a nice tutorial for a simple glowing LED design from fgpa4fun.com, but I can't get the testbench to output a waveform for the LED (it just stays at value X).

I'm using a Zybo Z7 board with clock 125MHz.

Below is the module:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module LED_Glow(i_Clk, o_LED);
input i_Clk;
output o_LED;

// Clock frequency 125MHz, glow frequency 1Hz -> count up to 125MHz
reg [26:0] r_Count;
wire [5:0] w_Intensity = r_Count[26] ? r_Count[25:20] : ~r_Count[25:20];
reg [6:0] r_PWM;

always @(posedge i_Clk)
    begin
        r_Count <= r_Count + 1;
        r_PWM <= r_PWM[5:0] + w_Intensity;
    end

assign o_LED = r_PWM[6];
    
endmodule
```

and this is my testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module tb_LED_Glow();

reg r_Clk;
wire w_LED;

LED_Glow one(.i_Clk(r_Clk), .o_LED(w_LED));

initial
    begin
        $monitor("r_Clk=%b, w_LED=%b",r_Clk, w_LED);
        r_Clk <= 1'b0;
    end
    
always #1 r_Clk <= ~r_Clk;

endmodule
```

I am able to synthesize, implement and program my device fine, and the LED glows as expected, but the simulated waveform looks like this, and I'm not sure why:

[image: Waveform]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the design module (`LED_Glow`), not in the testbench module (`tb_LED_Glow`).

The default value for `reg` types is x (unknown).  You declared `r_Count` as `reg`, which means it has the value of x at simulation time 0. At the 1st posedge of `i_Clk`, adding 1 to `r_Count` has no effect; `r_Count` remains x.  `r_Count` remains x for the duration of the simulation.

The same is true of the `r_PWM` signal.

You need to initialize these signals with known values.  One way to do so is as follows:

```
reg [26:0] r_Count = 0;
reg [6:0] r_PWM = 0;
```

[image: waves]

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned before, the issue is on the design.
It is important that you add a reset in sequential logic design. The reset would ensure that the design starts from a known state. You can check this change on EDAPlayground [led_glow_tb](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/ETbv)